# Keyboard's capital shift key combinations acting really weird

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard

Hi i don't know where to put this question but my laptop's keyboard has been acting really weird i can't make capital n's with left shift but with right shift i can make capital n's, but for example i can make capital a's with left shift but not capital d's with right shift and i cannot make any capital f's with either shift keys. Does anyone know what causes this, i've tried reinstalling windows and checking if ubuntu had the same problem, this didn't change anything. but i feel like this almost can't be hardware related since all the keys seem to be working individually. I've only had this problem for a couple of days(i discovered it today and it can't have been going on any longer since i am a programmer and would have noticed.)

Laptop is relatively new its a medion erazer(something something) it works just fine with sticky keys and the onscreen keyboard doesn't work properly either if i type, it does work if i click.

A usb keyboard does work like it's supposed to.

Comment: Have you tried 1/ Another keyboard (USB)? 2/ The onscreen keyboard?

Comment: Onscreen has the same problem although you  can see that it recognises the shift being pressed also the laptop is only half a year old so it's pretty new.

Comment: What is your language setting? Could the shifts be used separately to provide diacritic (accent) marks on some characters?

Comment: My language is set to English and i've tried both us and uk keyboard configurations, but i've just tried to make é's for example but when i press ' it just places a ' immediately instead of allowing me to press another button like 'e" like its supposed to

Comment: Most systems come with a 1 year standard warranty. Get your receipt and call the manufacturer. You will probably have to ship it to them so they can troubleshoot it and do whatever is covered in the standard warranty and get it back to you. Sucks, but that's probably the reality of it. I've never heard of such a lousy thing on a system, so it's probably a faulty "anything" inside of it right now. Could be a thousand things.