# Unable to make capital "n" using the left "shift" and the capital "m" with the right "shift"

Tags: keyboard, shift

Yesterday I removed and put back after 5 minutes the battery of my ASUS VivoBook Pro 15 N580GD with win10 64bit. Laptop is 5 years old, never had a problem.
After that, everything seems to work normally except I can't make the capital "n" using the left "shift" and the capital "m" with the right "shift"!
But both work with the other "shift": the "n" with the right one and the "m" with the left one. Lowercase "n" and "m" work normally. All the other letters I can do them capital with both the left and right "shift".

But what is even more absurd is that I can do both the "n" and the "m" capital with the non-working "shift" by following these steps: I keep pressed "shift" then I keep pressed the "n" (or the "m"), when I release "shift" the letter in capital magically appears
Anyone have any idea what that might be and how to fix it?

Please note that I posted this issue in the Microsoft site [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/unable-to-make-capital-n-using-the-left-shift-and/0bece3b2-daa2-47b9-a02d-f54ef51adb19) and get pretty standard procedures, which I did with no result. Last hint was to do a clean installation which is not an option

I also read in this forum [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1111323/keyboards-capital-shift-key-combinations-acting-really-weird) which is very similar and did same test with no result

Anyone with any brilliant idea?

Comment: Try an external keyboard to help you narrow down the cause.

Comment: Yep just did it. It works well with external keyboard

Comment: I posted an answer for you and hope you will accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is try first with an External Keyboard.

If that works (you said it did) then your permanent fix is to replace the laptop keyboard.

Good luck with that.

If age is against the computer, it may be time to replace the computer.